# 暫定モデレーターを任命しました

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

ベータ版の間、コミュニティの成長をサポートし、運用を手助けするユーザーが必要です。そのためベータ期間中は、コミュニティからユーザーを数人選んで、一時的なモデレーターとして任命します。このやり方を取るに至った経緯は（英語になりますが）[こちらに説明があります](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)。（追記: [和訳しました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2692/19110)）

Stack Overflow日本語版では、以下のみなさんが当コミュニティにこれから起こるかもしれない問題を解決するためにボランティアをしてくれることになりました。

[image: ento]
[image: tomute]
[image: unarist]

当サイトを成功に導くためには努力が必要ですが、この3人は今までの貢献で非常にお世話になっています。引き続き力を貸してくれることをコミュニティ全体で期待しましょう。

#### 誰かを見落としてないですか？

もちろん貢献していただいている方はたくさんいらっしゃいます。当サイトを応援してくださる方が本当に多く、大変感謝しています。こちらで選ばなかった人に悪い思いをさせたいわけではありません。将来的にベータを卒業したら、モデレーターをこちらで勝手に選ぶのではなく、ユーザー全員が投票できる選挙を行います。そのタイミングまでは上記のモデレーター3人を応援しましょう。この3人が自分の時間をボランティアとしてこのコミュニティのために使ってくれています。一緒に成長しましょう。