# 暫定モデレーター

Tags: サポート, モデレーション, stackoverflow.blog

これは [Robert Cartaino](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/rcartaino/) 氏によって 2010 年 7 月に投稿された ["Moderator Pro Tempore"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) の和訳です。

---

[新しい Stack Exchange コミュニティたち](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)には、パブリック・ベータの際に多少のリーダー不在期間があります。我々運営側は、それぞれのコミュニティが彼ら自身のサイトを所有できるよう、多くの権限を渡しています。Stack Exchange チームがガイドになることはできても、それぞれのコミュニティが持つ要望を理解できるほどの基礎知識を持っているとは、必ずしも限らないからです。Stack Exchange Network の規模が大きくなるにつれ、このことがそれぞれのコミュニティの問題が的確に対処される保証を厚くしてきたのです。

[image: 多くの Beta サイトの名前が文字で羅列されています]

私が **これらのコミュニティから仮のモデレーター・チームを組織している** 最中なのはこのためです（パブリック・ベータに入ってから約 7 日頃に、大体 1 サイト 3 人ほどです）。これは一時的な、短期間の任命です。暫定モデレーターは[それぞれの新サイトに不可欠なもの](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/10/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)をよく考え、議論を促進させます。ベータ期間が終わり次第、コミュニティは自分たちで選挙を行うのが良いでしょう。

Stack Exchange のモデレーターは興味深い課題があります。[モデレーターの通常の活動](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/19110)の他にも、彼らの職務には **連絡係** になるというものがあります。つまり、個々のコミュニティと Stack Exchange チームとを繋ぐ役割です。

[image: Robert Cartaino さんのプロフィール画像です。彼はモデレーターだ、という表示が出ています。]

モデレーターとは Stack Exchange Network における各サイトの代表です。

- それぞれのサイト上でモデレーターは、サイトのメンバーがサイト上での問題を解決する手段を持てるように、彼らのできる範囲で確認します。
- モデレーターは必要に応じて、運営チームを含め、同じサイトや(ネットワーク内の)別サイトのモデレーターに助けを求めることができます。
- もし、ある **特定の** サイトのための機能の要求があった場合、そのサイトのメタでそのアイディアについて議論することになります。もしそのアイディアが良いものなら、モデレーターがそれを Stack Exchange チームに持ち込むことになります。

**それぞれのサイトの成功のため、我々はコミュニティの中のリーダーを必要としています**。そしてモデレーターは、自分たちのサイトが充分な存在感を持っていることを保証するのです。

[image: 崖の上に羊が5匹並んでいます。崖からは1匹の羊が落ちています。崖の下には "LEADERSHIP: it depends on the leader" と書かれています。]

もちろん、もしそのアイディアがコアのエンジンに関わるものであったり、種々のサイトに渡って適用されるようなものなのであれば、そのアイディアは Stack Exchange の "首都" である [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) に上げられるべきです。

### 暫定モデレーターの選定方法

パブリック・ベータ期間に入って 1 週間ほど経ったら、我々は **コミュニティの発展に深く携わっているメンバーを探します** 。これはつまり、次のようなメンバーのことです。

- 高い信用度を得ていて、活発に、かつ一貫して参加している。
- メタにおけるコミュニティ形成活動に興味を示している。
- すべての投稿において仲間のコミュニティメンバーに対する忍耐と尊敬の念を示し、自らお手本となっている。
- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/19110)で議論されているような無形の特性を示している。

また、以下についてはおまけで評価します。

- メタサイトと本サイトの **両方** に参加しているメンバー（つまり、コミュニティの形成と、その界隈の専門知識との両方に興味があること）。
- Area 51 への参加、ソーシャル・ネットワークからの参照数、あるいはサイトについてのブログ投稿。
- コミュニティを育てる能力や興味を既に示しているメンバー。

こうして選ばれた候補者に連絡が行き、そしてベータ期間が終わって正式な選挙が行われるまでの間の暫定モデレーター 3 人が選ばれることになります。通常のモデレーターが持つ権限の他に、彼らは以下のことができます。

1. 共同でモデレーションを行いコミュニティを自治するための、特別なチャットルームにアクセスできます。
2. ドメインの名前、デザイン、FAQ など、サイトの特性を選ぶためのプロセスをまとめる。
3. コミュニティーからの支持を集め、サイトの宣伝活動を推進する。

つまり、**暫定モデレーターとは自分たちのサイトを成功させるため、Stack Exchange チームの耳となり援助することです！**

### あなたのコミュニティに充分な存在感があることを確認しましょう

もしあなたのメタサイトにモデレーター選出のための投稿が無ければ、今始めましょう！　暫定モデレーターの認定は、サイトが作られて約 2 週間後に始まります。我々が推薦の案内を受ければ受けるほど、我々の決定がより見識あるものになります。

以下はモデレーターを選出する標準的なやり取りの例です。

- モデレーター候補を選出するためのメタポストを作る。上で述べたようなモデレーターの特性を列挙し、このブログ投稿へリンクする。<sub>（訳注：原文ではここに本文内へのリンクがありましたが、リンク切れのため反映していません。）</sub>
- 自薦ももちろんOKで、むしろ歓迎しています。多くのサイトでは、たくさんのユーザーが立候補するほどの充分な時間が経っていません。自薦の場合は単に「モデレーターに興味があります。詳しくは私のプロフィールや活動履歴を見てください。」ということを記すだけで十分です。
- その投稿をモデレーターに通報してください（Stack Exchange のスタッフが通知を見ています）。これはその投稿に [注目] タグを付け、メインの Q&A サイトにおいて注意を引き付けるためです。
- それぞれの推薦は（候補者ごとに）別々の回答として投稿してください。我々がそのユーザーの活動を閲覧できるよう、そのユーザーの（本家とメタの）プロフィールへリンクしてください。Area 51 への参加、他のサイトへの参加、サイトを評価したり知らせたりするブログ投稿など、その他の活動に対するリンクも助けになるでしょう。
- 第三者によって推薦が投稿された場合、推薦された方はその回答を編集・追記して、受け入れるかどうかを明らかにしてください。必要なら、自分について更に何か書いても構いません。

何よりも、暫定モデレーターを尊重し、理解してください。あなたのコミュニティのメンバーは自らの時間をボランティアで使っており、活動しながらやり方を学んでいるのです。これは皆のための学習体験なのです。

---

<sub>誤訳等ありましたら直接編集頂けると幸いです。コメントでのご指摘も歓迎いたします。</sub>

Comment: 原文の「Make Sure Your Community is Well Represented」はすぐ下に続く暫定モデレーターの選出・推薦に対する見出しで、恐らく「推薦文には候補者の活動=人となりがよく分かるように記述しましょう」くらいの意味合いなのかなぁと思います(だいぶ意訳が入りますが)。

Comment: あとは「我々」「彼、彼ら」「あなた」等が直訳だとそれぞれ誰を指しているのか分かりづらいので、しつこくならない程度に補足してあげると読みやすいのかなと。この記事内では「我々=運営スタッフ」「彼、彼ら=暫定モデレーター、または利用者」「あなた、みんな、メンバー=利用者」ですよね？

Comment: "well represented" の部分は上手く訳出できていないと思っていました。適当な訳がもしあれば編集頂ければと思います。原文には二箇所に "well represented" が出てきていて、時間軸と文脈を勘案するに「運営チームは暫定モデレーター選出のために活動しているつもりだが、あなたのサイトが忘れられていないか確認してください」程度の意味だと思っています。

Comment: we や you は私の訳の時点でも適度に省略したり情報を追加したりしていて、私向けにはこれで読みやすいつもりでした。読みやすさの部分には個人差がありそうですね……。私にも翻訳論の教科書かなにかを読むべきときが来たのかもしれません。