# 新モデレーター: nekketsuuuさん就任のお知らせ

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

私たちにとってはStack Exchange Network の全てのサイトが大切であり、各コミュニティーの成長を心から期待しています。しかしそれは弊社とコミュニティの橋渡しをしてくれる[モデレーター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)の手助けがなければ達成できません。

Unaristはこれまでモデレーターとしてスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版を大きく牽引してくれましたが個人的な理由で退任することとなりました。スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のモデレーターの統計をみると、コミュニティーが新しいモデレーターを必要としていることは明らかです。スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版はベータ版であるため投票による選挙を行うことができません。よって、現在のモデレーターの推薦とサイトへの参加統計に基づき["暫定" モデレーター](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2692/19110)のポジションの申し出をしました。

そしてこの度、オファーがアクセプトされ、@nekketsuuu を新モデレーターとして発表できることを大変嬉しく思います！

> #### nekketsuuuさんとは？
>
> 私は広島県出身の学生で、普段は型理論や形式手法まわりの勉強をしています。
>   余暇には、SF を読んだり、アニメを見たり、ランダムに音楽を聞いたりしています。
>
> はじめて Stack Exchange Network に投稿したのは 2016 年 9 月のことで、Computer Science Stack Exchange への投稿でした。
>   ゲーミフィケーションに基づいた Q&A システムが面白く、徐々にのめりこんでいき、今に至ります。
>
> コミュニティモデレーターに なるにあたっては、質問者と回答者が、共に楽しめる環境作りのお手伝いができればと思います。
>
> スタック・オーバーフロー 日本語版のユーザーのみなさん、今後とも興味深いご投稿を楽しみにしております :)
>
> [image: nekketsuuu]

[親切になろうポリシー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)のお手本となり、根気強く新規ユーザーを手助けする、そしてコミュニティの成長と成功に心からの興味を示してくれる @nekketsuuu は、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版モデレーターポジションの最適任者であると思います。スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版はこの変化によってさらに向上されると信じております。

皆で、@nekketsuuu を歓迎しましょう！

Comment: @unarist さん、今までありがとう！

Answer (score 17):

@nekketsuuu さんがモデレータになることに +1 です;

個人的に、モデレータをするにあたって一番重要な性質は、 Be Nice であることだと思います。特に、スタックオーバーフローはユーザー主導のコミュニティなので、モデレーションする際にはそれぞれの参加者に敬意を払う必要があると考えます。その中でも、決まった仕組み化によって対応できなかった問題に対応することが求められるのがモデレータなので、 Be Nice はより重要になると思います。

@nekketsuuu は、おそらくコミュニティのメンバーの中で、特に新規ユーザーに対しては、もっとも Be Nice を実践している人たちの一人だと思います。新しいユーザーが、スタックオーバーフロー的な仕組みから外れてしまったような投稿や行動をした場合などには、 @nekketsuuu はやってきて、そのユーザーの何がスタックオーバーフロー的ではないのか、その理由は何故か、改善をお願いできないか、などを親切なトーンで指摘しています。

実際、私がモデレータに上がってきた通報に対応しようと思った際に、その投稿を見てみると、それはすでに @nekketsuuu のコメントがあり、それによってとりたてた対応はもう必要なくなっている、ということもしばしばあります。彼がモデレータとなって、より実践できる行動が増えることは、このコミュニティにとってのプラスになると思います。